# Can't locate cause of "Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysql_query() " error

Tags: mysql

I get the following error

> Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysql_query()

On the following code

```
UPDATE `TK60_ALLDATA` SET `thc_140`='B' WHERE (`Flat id`='THE BUNGALOW' OR `HouseName`='THE BUNGALOW' OR `HouseNumber`='THE BUNGALOW') AND `Postcode`='NN14 1NJ';
```

But can't find the cause at all! Whats causing it?

Full php code:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `TK60_ALLDATA` SET `thc_140`='$band' WHERE (`Flat id`='$houseNum' OR `HouseName`='$houseNum' OR `HouseNumber`='$houseNum') AND `Postcode`='$oPostcode';")or die(mysql_query());
```

Comment: Are there any triggers on the table being updated?  What is the code that is calling the query?

Comment: The full php code is added to the question however the error occurs doing a direct MySQL query, and no triggers

Comment: Is it happening ALL the time, or just under certain circumstatnces of data values.  By building with embedded variables are you open to SQL-Injection?

Comment: The variables are never defined by user input, and yea it's happening all the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think the problem is in the second call of mysql_query:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `TK60_ALLDATA` SET `thc_140`='$band' WHERE (`Flat id`='$houseNum' OR `HouseName`='$houseNum' OR `HouseNumber`='$houseNum') AND `Postcode`='$oPostcode';")or die(mysql_query());
```

in the die() function you should use mysql_error() instead of a second mysql_query() call..

Comment: Considering the second mysql_query() is trying to execute using no arguments I'd agree